# Compare a datetime string with a datetime instance Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to compare a string with a datetime in it and a datatime instance

```
if datetime.fromisoformat(item[1]) < datetime.datetime.utcnow():
```

with "`item[1]`" being `str("2021-07-02 23:09:09.936720")`  but it always raises the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

I can't find a way to fix this error since I don't see the exact problem, thanks a lot if you could help :)

Comment: use `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.datetime.utcnow()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem is in the second part of the if-statement.

> datetime.datetime.utcnow()

The *utcnow()* method call should be written as **datetime.utcnow()**

I tried it on my local machine and this is the code that worked for me:

```
from datetime import *
var = "2021-07-05 23:09:09.936720"

if datetime.fromisoformat(var) < datetime.utcnow():
    print("Less!")
else:
    print("Not less!")
```

NOTE: Important part is to import the module using **"from datetime import *"**, otherwise the **fromisoformat()** method wouldn't be imported.